# How to get locations of asm statements with clang frontend

Tags: c++, clang, inline-assembly, llvm-clang, libtooling

Sample code:

```
int f_i32() {
  __asm {
    mov eax, 1
    mov edx, 1
  }
}
```

AST for this code:

[image]

I get only MSASMStmt in AST and nothing from inside it.

I want to extract locations of ASM statements inside **__asm** block.
How can get those with clang frontend and lib-tooling library?

Comment: Note that clang `-fasm-block` *doesn't* support leaving a return value in EAX and then falling off the end of a non-void function.  Only MSVC itself supports that.  It just inlines redundantly into `return f_i32() + f_i32()`.  https://godbolt.org/g/9dRCLM.  (But it's not optimized away like a GNU C asm statement that isn't `volatile` (implicitly or explictly).)

Comment: This isn't limited to MSVC-style asm blocks (`clang -fasm-blocks`).  With a GNU C inline-asm statement like `asm("mov $1, %0" : "=r"(ret));`, the AST only includes something about the output operand, not the asm template.  `GCCAsmStmt`...; Godbolt has an option for clang AST output: https://godbolt.org/g/ZsWXQb.  Note that it optimizes much better, because it's non-volatile so the compiler can run it once then add the output to itself.  MSVC-style asm is pretty crap; I wouldn't recommend it if you need efficiency.

Comment: I am interested in only the static locations of statements like 'mov eax, 1' from source code. How can I get it with AST?

Comment: No idea, sorry, otherwise I'd post an answer.  Just wanted to point out that your example function is useless and also undefined behaviour with clang.

Comment: Ok. But is part of code analysis and needs executable LOC.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

Idea is to iterate the ASM tokens returned by MSAsmStmt and get the location for each token.

```
    size_t asmTokens = asmStmt->getNumAsmToks();
    clang::Token* tokens = asmStmt->getAsmToks();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < asmTokens; ++i) {
        clang::Token token = tokens[i];
        size_t tokloc = SourceManager.getExpansionLineNumber(token.getLocation());
    }
```